# Can I fine tune MedPaLM model

Tags: nlp, language-model, finetuning, llm

Is it possible to fine-tune MedPaLM and MedPaLM2; Google's llms trained using PaLM specialized for medical domain. Can we fine-tune these models further to get more specialized models?